# Suddengly laggy although it worked completely fine with the same model before

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Searched around first but nothing helped, also mostly outdated stuff.

**System: Windows 10 pro, Ryzen 7 2700x, RTX 2070 Super, 16gb Ram**

I just wanted to add support edges. Theres a subd modifier with 1 level, it handled level 4 before without any problems. also tried hiding parts i`m not working on. Even just trying to move a single vertex around is impossible.

**Heres the video, i drag the vertex just a bit to the right to showcase the problem**:
**https://youtu.be/WYQiJ9F4-m8**

Comment: uptadet drivers, disabled autosave, only running the standart addons, restarted pc

Comment: Definitely looks like an out of memory issue of some kind.  Any way you can check on the state/usage of your GPU memory?

Comment: yeah, got 8GB GPU memory on the rtx 2070s... 
tried doing some crazy movements and upping subdivisions and it touched 40% (weird it should be lower i think, but this time i also had some video running). so its not a gpu issue. RAM was around 60-80%

Comment: Yeah, that's weird because normally rendering is CPU heavy and modelling is GPU heavy, so it should be GPU related. Maybe some kind of OpenGL/Vulkan issue? How is your CPU performance/PC memory during all this?

Comment: So i closed everything now except blender and tried upping subdivisions, tried beveling edge and during those loading/ freeze times, memory was about 50%, GPU barely affected peaking 8% and cpu hovered about 20-25% until i could move the view again. Really doesnt look like an hardware issue to me, as i tried exporting and editing it in cinema 4d without issues (shame i dont like modeling in c4d).

Comment: one thing that would interest me now if someone else opens the blender file has the same problem

Comment: Post the file and i'll try. I'm at my cottage right now, so I'm using a pretty dated rig  - A single R9 270X. If it works for me, then something's definitely off.

Comment: yes, thank you! https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nb2Eop74dtetjW7nXJK1mt3qH5giQbia?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, I can confirm I am experiencing the same performance issues. Every move takes a few seconds to "think about" almost as if blender is trying to redraw an entire complex scene every frame. I'm still trying to figure out why though. At first I thought it was your viewport samples, but nope. I'm currently testing ever way I know how.

Comment: its really weird, at first i thought it blender didnt like some drivers anymore, but you having the same issue with that scene makes it even weirder

Comment: I ultimately turned down the viewport samples (just to be safe - If there's some special case why you are using that value, this may not be necessay, but generally >1000 is very high). I found the most success by separating the mesh into pieces, and by turning off subdivisions. The large, complex piece of the plow has some sections with spacious geometry and some sections with really tight geometry, so I think the subdiv is going into way overkill in some places. If it's possible, try separating your mesh into several pieces, each containing similar "sized" geometry.

Comment: i`ll keep that in mind, many thanks! ill just add everything together after reworking the geometry and applied subdivision.  still fairly new to blender

gotta keep the geometry in mind a bit more from now on with subdivisions in mind, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. This is a bit of a strange one. It seems like blender has trouble with too much complexity all in one piece or something like that. I'm not sure though. If I find a more satisfying solution, i'll let you know.

Comment: thx mate, much appeciated. thats the first thing i encountered in blender that worked normally in other software. its not that bad though for now, since there is a workaround

Comment: No prob. Yeah, I don't know if it's something unique to blender 2.8, or just blender in general. I've been using since 2.76 and I have never encountered it as a problem yet, so at least it only seems to apply to unique scenarios. Hopefully, an even better blender user will come along and explain it better to both of us.